# Time complexity of recursive function with recursive call in the loop

Tags: algorithm, loops, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

I'm having problems with determining time complexity of next function:

```
void fun(int n)
{
  console.log(n);
  for(int i=n;i>1;i--)
  {
    fun(i/2);
  }
}
```

Observing it I can say that maximum height of recurrence tree would be `logn` and from Level 1 to Level `logn` there would be `n-k` calls on each level, but I don't know how to use this information. When I try to write recurrence equation I get something like:

`T(n)=T(n/2)+T((n-1)/2)+T((n-2)/2)+...+T(1)`,

but again I fail with trying to simplify it. How to solve this so I know what complexity is?

Answer (score 0):

I can't exactly find out it but at least for some values up to `n=1000` I draw its graph.

It shows for n input size how much operations is carried out.

```
100,102829
200,3694786
300,38847071
400,231707917
500,990735939
600,3395124890
700,9922266703
800,25708288066
900,60609216627
1000,132415444782
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Ok, you got right the depth of tree and number of nodes and you wrote the recurrent equation correctly, but lets go with different approach and see if we can notice any pattern so we can further simplify equation.

for n=1, complexity would be constant,c,lets say:

```
T(1)=1
T(2)=T(1)+1
T(3)=T(1)+T(1)+1=T(2)+T(1)
T(4)=T(2)+T(1)+T(1)+1=T(3)+T(2)
T(5)=T(2)+T(2)+T(1)+T(1)+1=T(4)+T(2)
T(6)=T(3)+T(2)+T(2)+T(1)+T(1)+1=T(5)+T(3)
...
```

Now i noticed pattern, that equation can be written as:

```
T(n)=T(n-1)+T(n/2)
```

Now,to approximate complexity it can be tricky, and i can't give you answer in that i believe is 100% true. But personally,  as first factor in equation is stronger than second i would say time complexity is at least `O(n)`.

Comment: "At least O(n)" is certainly true but a very weak bound. From my experiments, it seems to be much larger than O(n).

Comment: I found somewhere it could be 0(n^logn), but i absolutely have no idea how to get there.

Comment: O(n^lg n) is definitely an upper bound (which can pretty easily be derived using the upper bound of T(n) <= nT(n/2) + c), but still isn't tight.

Comment: Sir, I would be more than grateful  if you provide steps because i still cant figure it out.

Comment: See my answer for how to devise rough upper & lower bounds. I haven't been able to devise a tight bound however. I imagine it might be possible by varying the base of the logarithm.

Answer (score -1):

Let's devise an upper bound:

We have T(n) = c + sum<sup>n</sup><sub>i=2</sub> T(i/2).

Thus T(n) <= c + nT(n/2). This recursion is dominated by the leaves. The depth of the recursion tree will be log<sub>2</sub>(n). At each level, n is at least halved, so we have O(product<sub>i=0</sub><sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)-1</sup> n/2<sup>i</sup>) = O((n/2)<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>) = O(n<sup>log2(n)</sup>/2<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>) = O(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)</sup>/n) = O(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)-1</sup>).

Now for a lower bound:

We have T(n) >= c + n/2 * T(n/4).

Here the recursion tree will have height log<sub>4</sub>(n) = log<sub>2</sub>(n)/2.

So we have Ω(product<sub>i=0</sub><sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)/2-1</sup> n/4<sup>i</sup>) = Ω((n/4)<sup>log<sub>2</sub>(n)/2</sup>) = Ω(n<sup>log<sub>4</sub>(n)-1</sup>).

A tight closed form bound is probably harder to devise. You can get a rough ballpark estimate of the time complexity by calculating some values however:

```js
const maxN = 1e4
let xs = Array(maxN)
let tc = Array(maxN)
xs[0] = 1
tc[0] = 1
for (let n = 2; n <= maxN; n++) {
  xs[n - 1] = n
  tc[n - 1] = 0
  for (let i = n; i > 1; i--)
    tc[n - 1] += tc[(i >> 1) - 1]
}
Plotly.newPlot("plot", [{
  x: xs,
  y: tc,
  type: "plot"
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-2.25.2.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<div id="plot"></div>
```